# Use display flex while floating

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have two divs next to each other while floating right. I want these divs to remain the same height even when one div changes height. I believe i can use display: flex for this, however when i use this my float gets removed and the container gets placed top left.

```css
.flex {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.container-B {
  flex: 1;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B">
      <div>Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what should be your final result?

Comment: You're missing a `</div>` somewhere. It isn't clear where it is supposed to go (the indentation and the generate structure suggest different places).

Comment: If you omit ```display: flex``` for the container both content divs are on top of each other. Is this the desired behavior or should they be side by side?

Answer (score 0):

```
1.flex {
2  min-height: 300px;
3  margin: 0 auto;
4  display: -webkit-flex;
5  display: flex;
6}
7
8.container-B {
9  flex: 1;
10}
11
12.float-right {
13  float: right;
14}
15<div class="row flex">
16  <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B">
17    <div>Content</div>
18    <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B"> ------You forgot to close the <div>
19      <div>Content</div>
20    </div>
21  </div>
```

On line `18` you forgot to close the `<div>`.
Your code have to be like this:

```html
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B"></div>
      <div>Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also, tide your code, so the final result will look like this:

```css
.flex {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.container-B {
  flex: 1;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div class="float-right col-md-5 container-B">
      <div>
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Note: reduce the uses of `<div>`, use `<p>`, and `<h1,2,3,4,5,6>` instead]**